# Why is my button not an object? Is it because it is in the header?

Tags: button, getelementbyid, dashcode

When I run this code

```
var button=document.getElementById("button")

if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1)
{
button.style.left = 250;
}
```

The error is result of expression is not an object.   The object "button" is in the css file and it is the only one named button.  What am I doing wrong?  Does it have something to do with the button being in the header?  I'm using dashcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var button=document.getElementById("button").object
```

`getElementById` gives you the HTML DOM node for the button; you have to access its `object` to do all of the fancy Dashcode stuff to it. (I stumbled around with the same question for a while!)